# Prevent iframe scrolling until parent element reaches top/bottom of iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I've integrated a Dash dashboard into a Flask application. Basically I've sticked to this [medium](https://towardsdatascience.com/embed-multiple-dash-apps-in-flask-with-microsoft-authenticatio-44b734f74532?gi=4ef7bf19281c) and tailored it to my needs. Everything works as expected and the dashboard's content shows up as an iframe element. My problem is that the whole iframe situation feels a little hacky since the website has two scroll bars. The outer one for the main content and the inner one for the iframe. The UX is just not perfect as the iframe content sometimes starts scrolling before it's entirely visible.

There's one obvious solution to this problem that sadly isn't suitable for my dashboard. I could just increase the height of the iframe element until it fits the entire dashboard. That way I would get rid of the scrollbar. However, I have a sticky element in my dashboard that follows the user from a certain element onwards. Getting rid of the iframe's scrollbar would break the sticky element and I would really like to keep it.

Another solution I thought about that I'm just not capable of developing on my own is the following:
Enable main scrollbar and disable iframe scrollbar if the iframe element is not entirely visible. If the iframe element is entirely visible check if the iframe's scrollbar is at its topmost/bottommost position and enable upwards/downwards scrolling while disabling downwards/upwards scrolling.

I guess (hope) it's a lot harder to phrase than to actually code it. So I prepared some top-notch powerpoint visuals for easier understanding.

Blue background: main content
Red bordered rectangle: current view (scrollable)
Yellow rectangle: iframe (scrollabe)
[image: example]

Is there a way to achieve this behavior? I'm not particularly good at js & css so I would really appreciate if you could help me out.

Cheers

Comment: First of all, please go read [ask]. This site is not a code-writing service, you would need to at least make an attempt yourself. We can try and help you fix problems you run into while doing that, but this is not a place for extended “to do do a thing like this” tutorials.

Comment: Second, show us at least a [mre] of your current implementation. Right now, we can’t tell for sure whether these iframe contents are loaded from a different domain, but it sounds like it - and that would mean, you have no access to the iframe content _at all_, the Same Origin Policy prevents that. So any _“check if the iframe's scrollbar is at …”_ would be out of the question then to begin with.

Comment: You don't have control over that.